How to query locations/customTypes
How can I query locations in my table which a the nearest to a given position?
a.schema({
  Post: a.model({
    location: a.customType({
      lat: a.float(),
      long: a.float(),
    }),
    content: a.string(),
  }),
});

https://docs.amplify.aws/react/build-a-backend/data/data-modeling/add-fields/#specify-a-custom-field-type
I have read following post and the docs.
Unfortunately there is no example in the docs how to filter any data.

Such cases require you to use Lambda function where you have to write custom logic. You can then write a CustomQuery and connect that with this Lambda function as a data-source.

The example (https://docs.amplify.aws/react-native/build-a-backend/data/custom-business-logic/#step-2---configure-custom-business-logic-handler-code) provided does not show how to access the dataset.
